# Bind value in textbox in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button btnAdd , a textbox and list with a edit button btnEdit in a html file. When I click on btnAdd it insert a textbox value into list and when click on btnEdit I want to display selected value of list into Text box.

Below is my Component Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Hero} from './hero';   

@Component({
  selector: 'my-Home',
   templateUrl: 'app/Home/home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent  {  

   title = 'Tour of Heroes';
   newH : Hero;
   heroes = [new Hero(1, 'Windstorm'), new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'),new Hero(15, 'Magneta'), new Hero(20, 'Tornado')];

  addHero(newHero:string) {
     this.title ="Button Clicked";
      if (newHero) {    
      let hero =  new Hero(14,newHero);   
      this.heroes.push(hero);
     }
  } 

  onEdit(hero: Hero) {   
    // want to display selected name in textbox. 

  } 

 }
```

Below is Html code :

```
<input type = 'text' #newHero/>
<button (click)=addHero(newHero.value)>Add Hero!</button> 

    <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" >          
        <span >{{ hero.id }}</span> {{ hero.name }}        
       <button (click)=onEdit(hero)>Edit!</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Below is my class :

```
export class Hero {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string) { }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the hero name to the input text value:

```
<input type='text' [value]="selectedHero" #heroName/>
<button (click)="addHero(heroName.value)">Add Hero!</button> 

export class HomeComponent  {  
  selectedHero = '';
  onEdit(hero: Hero) {   
    this.selectedHero = hero.name;
  } 
 }
```

Comment: thanks for reply.Edit is working but Add new item in list on add button is not working which worked previously..

Comment: By the way, what you want to happen after you set the name on the textbox and you click add hero?

Comment: Thanks, Its working now. I am new in angular 2 and learning with this simple example. thanks again.

Comment: Now one last que. How to update that value and display in list with updated value on Edit button.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct. you should check if you already has the value on the list and if yes update this value. if you don't understand how please add new question and send me the link to the question to help you.

Comment: Thanks @FunStuff, I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215713/update-value-of-list-item-on-button-click-in-angular-2

Comment: Just me or does this code look incomplete, @Bazinga?